# Amount of line spacing, letter class

Tags: line-spacing, letters

I'm wondering what is the default amount of space (in pt and cm)  between "city, state 12345" and "Dear Mrs. Smith" when using the letter class.

The letter I'm referring to is here:
 https://www.latextemplates.com/template/plain-cover-letter

Thank you

Comment: `\the\baselineskip` for a 11pt default font size after a  `\large` command  is 14 pt (roughly 0.5 cm).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [`letter.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/letter.cls?view=co), this amount is `2\parskip`, which is equivalent to `2\medskipamount`, which is `15.32996pt`.

It forms part of the definition of `\opening` (highlighted below):

```
\newcommand*{\opening}[1]{\ifx\@empty\fromaddress
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
    {\raggedleft\@date\par}%
  \else  % home address
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    {\raggedleft\begin{tabular}{l@{}}\ignorespaces
      \fromaddress \\*[2\parskip]%
      \@date \end{tabular}\par}%
  \fi
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  {\raggedright \toname \\ \toaddress \par}%
  \vspace{2\parskip}% <-------------------------------
  #1\par\nobreak}
```